# Move SharePoint Farm SQL Database to Always On Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I'm working on an environment wherein I've a SharePoint Farm that uses a single SQL server as a backend. Lately I've configured that SQL server to be a part of an availability group and I want to change the default database for the SharePoint to use the listener of this availability group.

Can I do it directly by changing the default database server from Central Administration -> Application Management -> Specify the default database server.

Especially the primary node of the listener will have all the required databases and even the secondary node.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

**Stop Sharepoint gracefully**

1. Close all open SharePoint Management Shell windows, and all open command prompt windows.
2. On the server that is running Central Administration, stop the following services:

   - SharePoint Administration
   - SharePoint Timer
   - SharePoint Tracing
   - SharePoint User Code Host
   - SharePoint VSS Writer
   - World Wide Web Publishing Service
   - SharePoint Server Search
3. On the server that is running Central Administration, at a command prompt, type `iisreset /stop`.

**Point the web application to the new availability group IP by setting up SQL Server connection aliases**

1. This procedure must be performed on all servers in the SharePoint Server farm that connect to the instance of SQL Server that hosts the databases.
2. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the following:

   - The Administrators group
   - The db_owner fixed database role
3. Start the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
4. Expand SQL Server Native Client Configuration, right-click Aliases, and then click New Alias.
5. In the Alias Name box, enter the name of the new alias, which you are creating.
6. In the Port Number box, enter the number of the port the new alias will use to connect to SQL Server.
7. In the Protocol box, click the drop-down arrow and select TCP/IP. This is the protocol the new alias will use to connect to the SQL Server.
8. In the Server box, enter the IP or DNS of the availability group.
9. Repeat steps 3 through 8 on all servers in the farm that connect to the new instance of SQL Server.

**Restart Sharepoint**
1. On the server that is running the SharePoint Central Administration website, at a command prompt, type `iisreset /start`.

2. In the Microsoft Management Console Services snap-in, start all of the services that are related to SharePoint Server and IIS. These include the following services:

   - SharePoint Administration
   - SharePoint Timer
   - SharePoint Tracing
   - SharePoint User Code Host
   - SharePoint VSS Writer
   - World Wide Web Publishing Service
   - SharePoint Server Search

This is based upon https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/SharePoint/administration/move-all-databases
You are trying to move the database without actually moving the database.